# Highchart with Range Selector

Tags: highcharts

I bascially want 
[High Chart combo dual axes](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-dual-axes) with the range selector on [HighStock](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/basic-line).
How can I merge these two. 
or there is any other way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the combination:

http://jsfiddle.net/5eem7a2a/1/

But unfortunately `Highstock`'s only type of `xAxis` is `datetime`, so you cannot add `xAxis categories` here.

Another option would be to use `navigator` in `Highcharts` and set your own xAxis in the detail chart:

http://jsfiddle.net/b826C/1/

which also uses datetime in the navigator bar(pity).

The last option would be to use `Highcharts` `Master-detail`:

http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail

Answer (score 0):

The rangeselector is only in the highstock, you you should it.

Comment: Thats correct, that range selector is in Highstock, but I was wondering if there is any way to merge both of them.

Comment: Use highstock.js and call highcharts, like in the example:  (but data requier to be datetime). http://jsfiddle.net/vuo2c3k8/